# execute sql script using java

Tags: java, sql, execute

I want to execute sql script using java
Java program is:

```
import java.io.*;
public class script{

public static void main(String argv[]) {

try {
  String line;
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("psql -U mit -d d980 -h tpeux250.sgp.st.com -f C:/java program/script.sql");
  BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {        
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
  err.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

but i am getting the following errors

```
java.io.IOException:Cannot run program "psql": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start<Unknown Source>
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec<Unknown Source>
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec<Unknown Source>
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec<Unknown Source>
       at script.main<script.java:8>
```

Comment: *The system cannot find the file specified*

Comment: Can you run the command from the shell ?

Comment: Try it directly from your terminal!

Comment: Please use ProcesBuilder, that handles arguments and white spaces cleanly

Comment: jdbc seems the way to go...?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use this

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd.exe /c psql -U mit -d d980 -h tpeux250.sgp.st.com -f C:/java program/script.sql");
```

Comment: now errors are not coming..but its not going inside while loop..nothing is getting printed..can u figure out what can be the problem with the code

Comment: psql -U mit -d d980 -h tpeux250.sgp.st.com -f C:/java program/script.sql...this command?

Comment: first add psql command to your PATH variable or give whole path where your psql command installed then try to run in cmd and if in cmd it run then you will able to run from your java code

Comment: If i use this command in unix then what will come instead of cmd.exe?

Answer (score 2):

The location where the actual `psql` binary is isn't on your `PATH` environment variable.

To verify run the following command from your terminal.

```
echo %PATH%
```

If the `psql` *bin* directory is missing, add it to your path as follows

```
set PATH = %PATH%;"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin"
```

and try to run your `psql` script from the terminal again. If that solves your problem, add the `bin` directory permanently (you'd have to since your Java program is sort of running in a different terminal)

> My Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings (in the left pane). Select Environment Variables at the bottom and modify PATH to add your psql "bin" directory after a ";" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your command from java try executing it in the terminal. I see C:/java program and hoping it is Windows go to run(windows+R) and execute `cmd`. In the terminal try executing your command.
In windows try back slash instead of forward slash

```
C:\>cd "c:\Program Files"
```

is successful whereas

```
 C:\Program Files>cd "c:/Program Files"
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

is not. So use `C:\java program\script.sql`